# Is hole punching cache method working in Magento2? How to implement in Particular Block in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, cache, holepunching

Can anyone please explain hole punching Cache method and how to implement in particular one block in Magento 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whole punching Cache is not the good idea at Magento 2.

Using layout set `cacheable="false"` for block means you have the disabling cache for the whole page.

If you want to get private of the content of current user then you should use  **customer-data JS library to store private data in local storage**.

Might be you have tried to  achieve [How to add a remove link on product detail page, if it's already added on wishlist in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238309/how-to-add-a-remove-link-on-product-detail-page-if-its-already-added-on-wishli) question answer.

**So in case, my suggestion to push user existing wishlist item product id 
to local storage and basic of that data active and deactivate the wishlist link.**

A good example of  this type of work is [Magento_InstantPurchase](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/InstantPurchase/)

Here.in module  Magento push instance purchase data means customer default shipping address and billing address  to local storage

> [Magento\InstantPurchase\CustomerData\InstantPurchase](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/InstantPurchase/CustomerData/InstantPurchase.php#L105)

See that class:

```
    public function getSectionData(): array
    {
        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return ['available' => false];
        }
    ......
        $paymentToken = $instantPurchaseOption->getPaymentToken();
        $shippingAddress = $instantPurchaseOption->getShippingAddress();
        $billingAddress = $instantPurchaseOption->getBillingAddress();
        $shippingMethod = $instantPurchaseOption->getShippingMethod();
        $data += [
            'paymentToken' => [
                'publicHash' => $paymentToken->getPublicHash(),
                'summary' => $this->paymentTokenFormatter->format($paymentToken),
            ],
            'shippingAddress' => [
                'id' => $shippingAddress->getId(),
                'summary' => $this->customerAddressesFormatter->format($shippingAddress),
            ],
            'billingAddress' => [
                'id' => $billingAddress->getId(),
                'summary' => $this->customerAddressesFormatter->format($billingAddress),
            ],
            'shippingMethod' => [
                'carrier' => $shippingMethod->getCarrierCode(),
                'method' => $shippingMethod->getMethodCode(),
                'summary' => $this->shippingMethodFormatter->format($shippingMethod),
            ]
        ];
        return $data;
    }
```

That data is read using  `customerData.get('instant-purchase')`
Checkout show knock js view read this data.

[`Magento/InstantPurchase/view/frontend/web/js/view/instant-purchase.js`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/InstantPurchase/view/frontend/web/js/view/instant-purchase.js#L65)

See how to use private data.
    https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

Comment: Can we get current product id from the local storage at the product detail page?

Comment: NO, you cannot get current product id from local storage. In this you can use a js variable which is save product id